# PHP - Referencing Namespace In Attribute with SimpleXML and XPath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, attributes, simplexml

I'm very new to SimpleXML and XPath, and while I have had success with several examples similar to this, this particular one seems to have me stumped.

I've tried accessing the dmd:surveyId attribute (of the Record node), without success.  I've tried adding the 'dmd:' prefix like this:

```
echo 'surveyId is...<h1>'.$xml_intellcont_report_abbrev[0]['dmd:surveyId'].'</h1><br>';
```

Thanks for any leads.

The PHP code:

```
<?php
$url = "test_bb.xml";


$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data');//
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('dmd','http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata');

$xml_report_abbrev_bb = $xml->xpath('//a:Record[@username="john-smith"]');


if($xml_report_abbrev_bb){
    echo $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->INTELL->CONTYPE;
    echo $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]['termId'].'<br>';
    echo 'surveyId is...<h1>'.$xml_intellcont_report_abbrev[0]['dmd:surveyId'].'</h1><br>';
} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}

?>
```

The XML ('test_bb.xml'):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data" xmlns:dmd="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata" dmd:date="2012-01-03">
    <Record userId="148" username="john-smith" termId="4" dmd:surveyId="12">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D" entryKey="Dylan" text="Dylan"/>
        <INTELL id="14" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2017-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Sales Tools</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History</CONTYPEOTHER>
        </INTELL>
    </Record>
    <Record userId="149" username="mary-smith" termId="4" dmd:surveyId="16">
        <dmd:IndexEntry indexKey="D2" entryKey="Dylan2" text="Dylan2"/>
        <INTELL id="14" dmd:originalSource="54TEX" dmd:lastModified="2012-04-18T10:54:29" dmd:startDate="2011-01-01" dmd:endDate="2011-12-31">
            <CONTYPE>Other Tools</CONTYPE>
            <CONTYPEOTHER>Sales History Part B</CONTYPEOTHER>
        </INTELL>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need look to some examples of code working with namespace. Many of them can be found on this site.

You can't point right to attribue if it's from another namespace. A correct way to get an atrributes from namespace 'dmd' is:

```
if($xml_report_abbrev_bb){
    echo $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->INTELL->CONTYPE;
    echo $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]['termId'].'<br>';

    $surveyId = $xml_report_abbrev_bb[0]->attributes(('http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata'))['surveyId'];
    echo 'surveyId is...<h1>'.$surveyId.'</h1><br>';  // <h1>12</h1>

} else {
    echo 'XPath query failed';  
}
```

Comment: You have the syntax for `->attributes()` wrong. It's either `->attributes($ns_uri)` or `->attributes($local_prefix, true)`. So in this case either `->attributes('http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/data-metadata')` or `->attributes('dmd', true)`. The second is easier to type, but more likely to break if the source XML changes slightly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thx. Updated

Comment: Thanks - as far as the prefixes for the namespaces are concerned, do the prefixes created using 'registerXPathNamespace' (in xpath) and 'define' (simplexml) behave in much the same way?

Comment: @buck1112 Registering prefix make availiable to use it in xpath - https://eval.in/942676 but, what's about getting attribute and children, - you should set the namespace in every query and will get only those items that from that namespace as if there would be different xml or path in xml